# VB.NET - Given a date, how can I get the date of last four fridays?

Tags: vb.net, date

Given today's date want to get the date of the each Friday for the last four weeks.

Comment: What if today is a friday, is it included?

Comment: Tim Schmelter - Yes if today was Friday it would pick it up. But if you add this above the while loop  "currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(-3)" it will not pick the Friday of this week up.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easy LINQ approach:

```
Dim today = Date.Today
Dim lastFridays = From d In Enumerable.Range(0, Int32.MaxValue)
                  Let dt = today.AddDays(-d)
                  Where dt.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday
                  Select dt
Dim lastFourFridays As Date() = lastFridays.Take(4).ToArray()
```

Since it's not the most efficient approach, here is a query that is still readable and maintainable but only searches the first friday and then takes only every 7th day:

```
Dim lastFriday = lastFridays.First()  ' reuse of above query '
Dim fridays = From d In Enumerable.Range(0, Int32.MaxValue)
              Let dt = lastFriday.AddDays(-d * 7)
              Select dt
Dim lastFourFridays As Date() = fridays.Take(4).ToArray()
```

Comment: Doesn't seem very efficient to look at every previous day until you find four Friday's.  Just an opinion.

Comment: @dbasnett: It's just a loop from 0 to 34 (at a maximum). Don't underestimate the power of modern CPUs. So until this is not a performance contest i chose the most maintainable and readable approach.

Comment: My first computer, IBM 1620, makes today's CPU's speed astounding.  However, I see too often little inefficiencies, that when added together, become large.  On a one off you are correct.

Comment: @dbasnett: ok, i have added another LINQ approach which keeps readability but is more efficient.

Comment: the readability depends on the reader, don't you agree.  You and I understand it...  The other answers are equal from a readability / maintenance perspective, except for mine.  Mine might need the math to be explained in more detail, though I might argue there are only six cases to try.  I will assume that if you needed a million previous four Fridays based on some random start date every 5 seconds you wouldn't use LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my way:

```
Function Last4Friday(ByVal StartDate As Date) As array
    Dim L4F()
    Dim mDate as date = StartDate
    For value As Integer = 1 To 7
        mDate = mDate.AddDays(-1)
        If mDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday Then
        L4F = {mDate, mDate.AddDays(-7), mDate.AddDays(-14), mDate.AddDays(-21)}
        exit for
    End If
    Next
Return L4F

End Function
```

Edit: If you need to check the inserted date and you want it returned in the array you may simply use:

```
Dim mDate as date = StartDate.AddDays(1)
```

instead of

```
Dim mDate as date = StartDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  It doesn't use a loop to find the starting Friday.

```
        Dim someDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now

        If someDate.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Friday Then
            'do the math to get a Friday
            someDate = someDate.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Friday - someDate.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek - 6)
        End If

        Dim last4Fridays As New List(Of DateTime) From {someDate, someDate.AddDays(-7), someDate.AddDays(-14), someDate.AddDays(-21)}
```

All of the other suggestions have used a loop to find the starting Friday.  If this code is used infrequently then how the starting Friday is determined might not matter.

edit: as function

```
Function FindLastFourFridays(someDate As DateTime) As List(Of DateTime)
    'Find first Friday to include
    If someDate.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Friday Then
        someDate = someDate.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Friday - someDate.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek - 6)

        ' uncomment these two lines if you do not want initial someDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday to be included
        'Else 
        '    someDate = someDate.AddDays(-7)
    End If
    'build the return (four fridays)
    Dim last4Fridays As New List(Of DateTime) From {someDate, someDate.AddDays(-7), someDate.AddDays(-14), someDate.AddDays(-21)}
    Return last4Fridays
End Function
```

Comment: It seems to have the same execution time of my code (tested on .net fiddle) but I like your formula

Comment: @genespos - our return types are different.  If you made them the same return types and picked 7/23/2015 as a date how would they compare?

Answer (score 1):

You may consume this one, which returns a list of such dates and excludes the one if the *specifiedDate* date is *Friday*:

```
Public Shared Function GetLastFourFridays(specifiedDate As DateTime) As List(Of DateTime)
    Dim dtm As New List(Of DateTime)()
    Dim dt As DateTime = specifiedDate
    For i As Integer = 0 To 6
        dt = dt.AddDays(-1)
        If dt.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday Then
            dtm.Add(dt)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    dtm.Add(dt.AddDays(-7))
    dtm.Add(dt.AddDays(-14))
    dtm.Add(dt.AddDays(-21))

    Return dtm
End Function
```

and the way you use it is:

```
Dim dtm As List(Of DateTime) = GetLastFourFridays(DateTime.Now)

For Each d As var In dtm
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Date: {0}, Day: {1}", d.ToString(), [Enum].Parse(GetType(DayOfWeek), d.DayOfWeek.ToString())))
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This function does not need to be passed a date it picks up today's date and gets the last four Friday's from today. It can be changed around to get any day of the week.

```
    Dim todaysDate As Date = Date.Today
    Dim oldDay As Integer
    Dim thisWeek As Date

    Dim firstWeek As Date
    Dim secondWeek As Date
    Dim thirdWeek As Date
    Dim fourthWeek As Date


    'finds the Friday of the end of the current week No mattter what day you are working

    Dim daycount As Integer
    'use this to check specific dates "Dim datetime As New DateTime(2015, 4, 13)"
    oldDay = Weekday(todaysDate)
    thisWeek = todaysDate

    If oldDay < 6 Then
        daycount = 6 - oldDay
        thisWeek = thisWeek.AddDays(+daycount)
    ElseIf oldDay > 6 Then
        daycount = oldDay - 6
        thisWeek = thisWeek.AddDays(-daycount)
    End If

    Dim currentDate As Date = Now
    Do While Not currentDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday
        currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(-1)
    Loop

    fourthWeek = currentDate.AddDays(-21)
    thirdWeek = currentDate.AddDays(-14)
    secondWeek = currentDate.AddDays(-7)
    firstWeek = currentDate
```